# Why statcounter visitors stats is not same as Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, visitors, statcounter

On July 11, 2013 my website's visitors count according to Statcounter is 761 and according to Google Analytics it is 1010.

Some days both sites would show the same count but some days it would vary. What is the reason for these variations? If these kind of variations are quite natural means which site should I follow?

See these images for reference:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are both pieces of code in the same place on the page? If you have your Analytics code at the top of the page, and your Statcounter code at the bottom, it's possible that some users are leaving before the page is entirely loaded, so you're Analytics code would be executed, but you're Statcounter code would not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every tool for visitors' counting works differently. Google Analytics uses 5 kinds of cookies for tracking visitors, but Statcounter may use the different ones.

The second reason may be in different implementation of codes: Google Analytics loads asynchronously while Statcounter, probably, loads synchronously.